# How do creation operators change with time in an interacting theory?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, field-theory

When studying the quantization of a field theory with free fields, the creation operators $a^\dagger(k)$ are independent of time. In an interacting theory, they are time-dependent, and therefore $a^\dagger(k, -\infty)$ is not equal to $a^\dagger(k, +\infty)$. I would like to understand better what is the form taken by this difference : how exactly do they differ ? What are the physical consequences ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let us consider a real, scalar field theory for simplicity (and metric signature $+ - - -$). In the free theory, one can use the mode expansions of the field $\phi(x)$ and its canonical conjugate momentum $\pi(x)$ to derive the following expressions for the creation and annihilation operators:
$$ a(p)=i\int d^3x\ e^{ipx}\overset{\leftrightarrow}{\partial_0}\phi(x),\ a^\dagger(p)=-i\int d^3x\ e^{-ipx}\overset{\leftrightarrow}{\partial_0}\phi(x)$$
where $g\overset{\leftrightarrow}{\partial_0}f:=g\partial_0f-(\partial_0 g)f$. This relation is always true (and exact) in the free field theory.

In the interacting theory, one makes the *assumption* - usually accompanied by some hand-waving argument about 'turning off interactions in the distant past and future' - that these relationships still hold asymptotically (i.e. as $t\to \pm \infty$). Now, we want to find out how much $a$ and $a^\dagger$ change with time, so we consider the following:
$$\Delta a(p)=a(p,\infty)-a(p,-\infty)=\int\partial_0 a(p,t)\ dt=i\int d^4x\ \partial_0
\left(e^{ipx}\overset{\leftrightarrow}{\partial_0}\phi(x)\right)$$
One simply writes out these derivatives, and uses an additional assumption about the behavior of $\phi(x)$ at infinity to cancel some terms, finally arriving at 
$$\Delta a(p)=i\int d^4x\ e^{ipx}(m^2+\partial^2_t-\partial_i^2)\phi(x)=i\int d^4x\ e^{ipx}(\square+m^2)\phi(x) $$
This immediately shows that $\Delta a(p)$ is zero in the free theory, since the free field obeys the Klein-Gordong equation $(\square+m^2)\phi=0$, reflecting the fact that $a(p)$ is time-independent in this case. However, in an interacting theory the equation of motion is different and (generally) non-linear (e.g. $(\square+m^2+\lambda\phi^3)\phi=0$ in the case of $\phi^4$-theory), therefore $\Delta(p)$ will not vanish in the interacting case. It is easy to derive a very similar expression for $\Delta a^\dagger(p)$, which can be given the same interpretation.

**Addendum** (18-12-2014):

It turns out that it is not completely straightforward to find a good interpretation for the main expressions. However, I believe I have now found a good mental picture. To make it a little more clear, however, we have to do some more work. From the expressions for $\Delta a(k)$ and $\Delta a^\dagger(k)$ it is quite straightforward to derive the LSZ reduction formula for $N$ incoming particles with momenta $p_i$ and $M$ outgoing particles with momenta $k_i$ (in position space). If one then performs a Fourier transform, we find :

\begin{align}\langle k_1\dots k_M|S|p_{1}\dots p_{N}\rangle 
&=(2\pi)^4\delta^{(4)}\Big(\sum P\Big)
\prod_{i=1}^M i(k_i^2+m^2)\prod_{j=1}^Ni(p_i^2+m^2)\\
&\hspace{1cm}\times i\tilde G_{M+N, c}(p_1,\dots,k_{M-1})\\
&=(2\pi)^4\delta^{(4)}\Big(\sum P\Big)
\Big(i\tilde G_{2, c}^{(0)}(k_1)\Big)^{-1}
\dots\Big(i\tilde G_{2, c}^{(0)}(p_N)\Big)^{-1}\\
&\hspace{1cm}\times i\tilde G_{M+N, c}(p_1,\dots,k_{M-1})
\end{align}

Here, it is more simple to give an interpretation. The final 'big' propagator basically takes the $N$ initial particles and lets them time-evolve, *including the interaction terms*, to $M$ particles in the 'out'-state - it's basically a black box. Then, the product of inverse *free* (note the superscript $(0)$) propagators can be interpreted as subtracting off the free time evolution, of all the particles individually.

With this in mind, we can give the same interpretation to the expression for $\Delta a$ and its hermitian conjugate: We can interpret the $(\square+m^2)$ as 'subtracting off' the 'free' time evolution, keeping only the part that is due to the interaction (as we know, the free creation/annihilation operators should be time-independent). I'm aware that this is *very* handwavey, but I think that's the best I can do in terms of providing an intuition for what 'it means' - of course one should mostly just *shut up and calculate* ;)

Comment: Why do you guys so often answer simple questions by referring to really complex frameworks like relativistic QFT? This is just a question about interacting Hamiltonians and has absolutely nothing to do with path integrals. Adding relativity on top of path integration just to answer a question about interacting Hamiltonians seems weird. I really would like to know the answer to this, I'm not just complaining :)

Comment: @DanielSank It's because that's where we learn most of our field theory ;) Feel free to add a better answer if you can! And honestly, I don't think relativistic QFT is harder; maybe it's *you* who's biased ;)

Comment: @DanielSank Also, I'm not sure where you're getting 'path integration' in this answer. There is no path integration going on here; this is canonical quantization.

Comment: Ooof, you're right about the path integration. Sorry, my mistake. Oh man, that first comment of mine doesn't make any sense, sorry.

Comment: I have seen this derivation in textbooks indeed, but the physical meaning eludes me. Do the operators vary in norm, or in phase ? What is the difference between the asymptotic states created ?

Comment: That said, the reference to relativity, the metric, and the Klein-Gordon equation do seem like overkill.

Comment: @DanielSank: It is not a complex framework; a real scalar field is literally as simple as you can get in quantum field theory. Also, keep in mind that answers are not just for the OP, they are for the whole SE community, so you really have no right to complain.

Comment: @JamalS: While it is true that a real scalar is the simplest field theory, it is definitely not the simplest case in which you can discuss the evolution of raising/lowering operators in an interacting system. Furthermore, it is precisely because the answers are for the whole community that I encourage them to be as simple as possible. As I am a member of the community, I don't see how it makes sense to tell me that I have no right to complain :)

Comment: @DanielSank the reference to the metric is only there to prevent confusions about tge sign in the exponent; it doesn't have some kind of profound meaning. Furthermore, the KG-eqn does nothing but express the free particle relativistic mass energy equivalence in operator terms, so it's not as advanced as you seem to think.

Comment: @DanielSank as far as I am concerned, this is not overkill. But I would also like to see a qualitative discussion on how  the operators differ.

Comment: @Whelp Given the fact that you've accepted my answer, I was wondering whether there was anything that keeps you from awarding the bounty. Is there anything that you're missing in my answer? If you are just waiting to see whether answers will pop up, I can of course understand.

Comment: That was a mistake on my part, I thought it was automatically awarded.